# django form validation not showing

Tags: django

i have this model :

```
class Member(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, editable=False, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=TITLE_TYPES, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name='Name') 
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name='LastName') 
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True, verbose_name='Gender') 
    dob = models.DateField('dob')
    redressno = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name='RedressNo')
```

form :

```
class MemberForm(ModelForm):
  dob = forms.DateField(required=False, input_formats=('%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y'))
  class Meta:
    model = Member
    exclude = ('profile',)
```

view :

```
MemberFormSet = formset_factory(MemberForm, formset=BaseFormSet)
    print request.method
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        signup_form = SignupForm(None, request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        # Create a formset from the submitted data
        member_formset = MemberFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if signup_form.is_valid() and member_formset.is_valid():
          print 'in valid'
          signup = signup_form.save(request.POST)
          for form in member_formset.forms:
            member = form.save(commit=False)
            member.profile = signup
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            member.save()
            #log-in to user
          user = authenticate(username = request.POST['username'], password = request.POST['password'] )
          auth_login(request, user)
          return redirect("/main") # Redirect to a 'success' page
    else:
        signup_form = SignupForm()
        data = {
          'form-TOTAL_FORMS': u'1',
          'form-INITIAL_FORMS': u'0',
          'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': u''
        }
        member_formset = MemberFormSet(data)
        # member_formset.total_form_count=0

    # For CSRF protection
    # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/ 
    c = {
          'form': signup_form,
          'member_formset': member_formset,
        }
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('registration.html', c, RequestContext(request))
```

Template :

```
    <form action="/registration/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="section">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</div>
   <h2>Members</h2>
      {{ member_formset.management_form }}
     {% for form in member_formset.forms %}
      <div class="item">
         {{ form.as_table }}
       <p style=""><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></p>
         </div>
        {% endfor %}
     <p><a id="add" href="#">Add another item</a></p> 
      <input type="submit" value=" Submit " />
```

and validation on memberform is not working .Please suggest why ?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Errors not appearing in template?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really explain your problem, but I'd guess you're not proceeding to validation of the member formset if the signup form isn't valid, because of this line:

```
if signup_form.is_valid() and member_formset.is_valid():
```

In Python, as in many other languages, `and` is shortcut-evaluated: that is, if the first element is False, the second is never evaluated. So `is_valid` is never run on the formset, so no errors are shown.

Instead, do this:

```
signup_valid = signup_form.is_valid()
formset_valid = member_formset.is_valid()
if signup_valid and formset_valid:
```

which ensures that both validations are performed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't see an `else` branch for invalid forms. Secondly, isn't the first parameter , `None`, erroneous for the form initialization in this line: `signup_form = SignupForm(None, request.POST)`.

Comment: if dob is submitted blank than how can `member_formset.is_valid()==True`

Comment: how can i validate dob in views?

Comment: Each valid form has a ``cleaned_data`` dictionary which should have ``dob`` key if the user provided it in the form. E.g. ``dob = form.cleaned_data.get('dob')``.

Comment: No need for an `else` for invalid forms, it will fall through to the end where the template is rendered. This is the correct pattern for validating Django forms.